# Python Error trying to send email by Hotmail. TImeout

Tags: python, sendmail

My code is as follows:

[image]

I always get this error when I try to send a email. Could you help me.

```
error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading the example in the manual located at https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

You would need to make sure your firewall operating system and LAN router allows outgoing traffic on port 25.

Also, set verbose debug level as per manual `server.set_debuglevel(1)`

Try sending out test emails via localhost using terminal commands, to make sure the os can definitely send out emails, and that it isn't a python code issue.

Comment: i do this command telnet smtp.live.com 587 and is blocked. Tahnk you.